# NUnit Parameterized tests: Setting the test description

Tags: c#, nunit, nunit-2.5

I have written some [Parameterized Tests](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=parameterizedTests&r=2.5.9), that use the ValueSourceAttribute for some of the test method arguments.

Here from the NUnit doc:

```
         | Complete Test Cases     |   Data for One Argument
---------|-------------------------|------------------------
Inline   | TestCaseAttribute       | RandomAttribute
         |                         | RangeAttribute
         |                         | ValuesAttribute
Separate | TestCaseSourceAttribute | ValueSourceAttribute
```

Is there anyway I can set the test description (specifically in the XML output) for the test cases generated by NUnit's combination of the parameters?

I'm using NUnit 2.5.9.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's not possible with `ValueSourceAttribute`, because it would need to merge all descriptions from all `ValueSource` items of all parameters of the parameterized test.

When using the `TestCaseAttribute` you can give a description and a test name that should be passed into the result XML.

An example:

```
[Test]
[TestCase("abc", TestName = "Simple value", Description = "This test uses a simple input value")]
public void TestIt(string value)
{
  ...
}
```

There are also some other "special" parameters you can set, see [here](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=testCase&r=2.5.9).

When you are absolutely keen about this feature, you can write your own `TestCaseProvider` addin. See [the NUnit documentation](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=testcaseProviders&r=2.5.9) for more information. This will likely solve your issue. But be warned, this is not a 5-minute thing.

Answer (score 0):

With `[ValueSource(...)]` there's no way, I'm afraid.